# Skip values in bidirectional_dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to implement NER using BERT-embeddings on whole documents. 
A document consists of several sentences, each sentence consists of tokens and has variable length. Now I create word embeddings with BERT for each sentence and pad each sentence. Then I want to perform NER with bidirectional LSTMs on *all* tokens of a document, not only on sentences.

If I do this without fine-tuning BERT (extracting features like with ElMo-embedding) then I can just remove the padded tokens and concat all sentences before I feed them into a bidirectional LSTMs.

But how can I do that in a fine-tuning setting?

My input has the following shape: [documents, sentences, tokens]

For BERT I reshape the input to: [documents * sentences, tokens]

Then I would like to put the output of BERT into an bidirectional_dynamic_rnn with the shape [documents, sentences * tokens]. Unfortunatelly the sentences contain padded tokens (zero) and the bidirectional_rnn should skip them.

I cannot use the sequence_length parameter of bidirectional_dynamic_rnn as the padded tokens may be inside of the sequence. For example, a 
document consists of two sentences:

```
   s1=[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]
   s1=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

If I concatenate the sentences I get

```
   s1+s2=[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

bidirectional_dynamic_rnn should now skip the zeros.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I have programmed a small example to sort the pad values to the end of the list. I'm not sure how efficient the solution works, but I hope it's helpful.

```
import tensorflow as tf

vec = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0]])

number_mask = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(vec, 0), dtype=tf.int32)
pad_mask = 1 - number_mask
index_list = tf.cumsum(tf.ones_like(number_mask), axis=-1) - 1
fill_values = tf.reduce_max(index_list, axis=-1, keep_dims=True) + 1
content = index_list * number_mask + pad_mask * fill_values
pad = index_list * pad_mask - number_mask

content_sort = tf.sort(content, axis=1)
pad_sort = tf.sort(pad, axis=1)

content_sort_mask = tf.cast(tf.less(content_sort, fill_values), tf.int32)
pad_sort_mask = tf.cast(tf.greater(pad_sort, -1), tf.int32)

result_index = content_sort * content_sort_mask + pad_sort * pad_sort_mask

result = tf.batch_gather(vec, result_index)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run([result]))
    # [array([[ 1,  2,  3, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50,  0,  0],
              [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)]
```